# Converting values to string

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
> head(custom.cn.data)
      Gene       Sample_name         CN
1: DDX11L1          F02         0.6788844
2: DDX11L1          C02        -0.9924524
3: DDX11L1          A07        -2.3833559
>
```

I want to convert values in CN column < 0 to Del and >0 to Amp

But I am getting error

```
> a %>% mutate(q = replace(CN, which(CN<0), Del))
Error in replace(CN, which(CN < 0), Del) : object 'Del' not found

> a$CN <- replace(a$CN, which(a$CN < 0), Del)
Error in replace(a$CN, which(a$CN < 0), Del) : object 'Del' not found
```

Any help?

Comment: You are getting these errors because you did not use quotes before and after `Del` and `R` looks for an object called `Del` instead of using the string "Del".

Comment: What happens to when CN is zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
custom.cn.data$new_column <- ifelse(custom.cn.data$CN < 0, "Del", "Amp")
```

In this scenario `CN == 0` would be `Amp`

Answer (score 4):

The following code would create a new column with the desired values, 0 values will have `NA` in this new column.

```
custom.cn.data[custom.cn.data$CN < 0, "CN_string"] <- "Del" 
custom.cn.data[custom.cn.data$CN > 0, "CN_string"] <- "Amp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to stay within one package (paradigm) for one problem. This will make the code more readable, easier to debug.

At the moment you have data as a *data.table* object from **data.table** package, then trying to add a new column using *mutate* from **dplyr** package, and within *mutate* using **base** *replace* function.

Solutions:

**data.table**

```
# update by row index
custom.cn.data[ CN < 0, NewColumn := "Del" ]
custom.cn.data[ CN >= 0, NewColumn := "Amp" ]
```

or use *ifelse*

```
custom.cn.data[, NewColumn := ifelse(CN < 0, "Del", "Amp") ]
```

**base**

see [@DavyCat's](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/11264/131) and [@haci's](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/11263/131) answers.

**dplyr**

Note, this will change the *data.table* into *data.frame*.

```
# ifelse
custom.cn.data <- custom.cn.data %>%
  mutate(NewColumn = ifelse(CN < 0, "Del", "Amp"))
```

or use *case_when*

```
custom.cn.data <- custom.cn.data %>%
  mutate(NewColumn = case_when(
    CN < 0 ~ "Del",
    CN >= 0 ~ "Amp"))
```